# How to get the DataSet to recognize the table names from stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

I have a stored procedures which returns about 5 tables and I am returning them something like this:

```
select <fields> from Products where ProductId = @ProductId
select <fields> from RelatedProducts where ProductId = @ProductId
select <fields> from MetaData where ProductId = @ProductId
```

well, you get the gist. Now in the Dataset, If I do this:

```
DataSet ProductDs = DAL.RetreiveProductMetadata(someInteger);

ProductName = DataSet.Tables["Products"].Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString();
```

Its throwing up an exception... well, error saying TableName is null and upon debugging, turns out, the table names are actually named as "Results1", "Results2" and so on.

I tried changing stored proc to:

```
select * From products AS Products
```

no effect.

How can I get C# to detect and use the Table Names from the database?

ps: I have all sorts of Coalesces and cases in the field, that shouldn't present a problem right?
Also, tried googling and banging head - neither worked.

Comment: What happens when you try to index a table with an int?

Comment: That would work, of course, but the point of me trying to access them by names is purely for readability purpose, so that I dont get confused with table[0] and [1] in the future (or any other coder who works on my code in the future)

Comment: Another kinda stupid question: did you try entering the table name in lower case? I remember having similar problems in the past but am not quite sure how I solved them, although I seem to recall something about case sensitivity.

Comment: um, The point is, when I debug, the Dataset shows table names as "Results1".. so case wouldn't be any different right? I will try it anyway, just in case

Comment: nope, no luck, as I said DataSet doesn't have any information of table names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The table name has no meaning in the result set because a query can contain many tables.

You should *know* what your resultsets are and should not have to derive table names.

Otherwise,

```
select 'Products' AS ThisTable, <fields> from Products where ProductId = @ProductId
```

Or JOIN first and unpick later

Or define your dataset.xsd etc up front and map according.

Comment: Yes I do know what my result sets are going to be but I am just trying to make it for the next guy to look at my code easier. Oh well, if its giving me extra work, better be productive and move on!! thanks!

Comment: @iamserious: if this is a Repository or DAL, you can hide the DataTables to higher levels of code. We use multiple result sets from procs but never considered the problem you report to be an issue...

Comment: can you please expand on that? in my DAL I have few strongly typed datasets and few stored procs that doesnt really fit in any table adapters so I have a class file to executes the stored procedure and returns the results. how do you access them via codes?

Comment: @iamserious: I'd have to check the finer points with other developers, but the Tables[0] etc only appears in one place so it's hidden. Or at least well commented...

Comment: I finally ended up renaming my tables manually, like Tables[0].TableName = "whatever"

Answer (score 3):

It's actually possible, you just need to load the table scheme first, which contains no data but information about the table structure including table names:

```
adapter.FillSchema(dataset, SchemaType.Source);
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

Seems this doesn't work on queries that are contained in the database (like you might use in MS Access), but it does the job for a regular table.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to retrieve a table by name from a dataset is: if you name it when filling from an adapter or manually name them later one table at a time:

```
adapter.fill(dataset, "nameoftable")
```

now when you access the ds in the future you can access by name; `ds.tables("nameoftable").rows`  etc.

or name them later.

```
_ds.tables(0).tablename = "nameoftable"
```