# Is it possible to parse a dataset by an aliased sql name?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

So we have a stored proc that returns three results:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name = "bob" AS Bob
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Name = "steve" AS Steve
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE Name = "jim" AS Jim
```

In C# I get a dataset back from the call:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=MySqlServer;integrated security=sspi;"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_spaceused";
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
```

I know that I can get the individual results using indexing:

```
var bob = ds[0];
var steve = ds[1];
var jim = ds[2];
```

Does the alias get passed to C#?
Is it possible to access the values by the alias?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the DataSet to recognize the table names from stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727786/how-to-get-the-dataset-to-recognize-the-table-names-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jtimperley has a good idea, but if you do it like this you can act upon the column name regardless of whether rows are returned or not.

SELECT '' AS TableName1, * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Name = "bob" AS Bob

SELECT '' AS TableName2, * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE Name = "steve" AS Steve

SELECT '' AS TableName3, * 
FROM Table3 
WHERE Name = "jim" AS Jim

Answer (score 1):

> Does the alias get passed to C#?

No it doesn't.

> Is it possible to access the values by the alias?

No.

You can only assign the alias / TableName after populating your `DataSet`. Basically you will end up loosing the alias assigned in the SQL Query inside your proc.

Answer (score 0):

No the cleanest solution but you could do something like this. Then query the known column for the type of table you've received.

```
SELECT 'Table1' AS TableName, * FROM Table1 WHERE Name = "bob" AS Bob
SELECT 'Table2' AS TableName, * FROM Table2 WHERE Name = "steve" AS Steve
SELECT 'Table3' AS TableName, * FROM Table3 WHERE Name = "jim" AS Jim
```